# Validation error with api connect on bluemix: Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'

Tags: api, yaml, ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I'm getting the error `Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'` with the following spec:

```
product: 1.0.0
info:
  name: account-information
  title: Account Information
  version: 1.0.10
  termsOfService: >-
    These API are a PSD2 implementation example. The service might be
    discontinued at any time
visibility:
  view:
    type: public
  subscribe:
    type: authenticated
plans:
  premium:
    title: Premium
    apis: {}
    rate-limit:
      value: 1000/1minute
      hard-limit: true
    approval: true
  default:
    title: Default Plan
    description: Default Plan
    approval: false
    rate-limit:
      value: 100/hour
      hard-limit: true
apis:
  account:
    $ref: account.yaml
  subscription:
    $ref: subscription.yaml
```

The full error message:

> Message : "Data does not match any schemas from "oneOf"", Chemin de données : "", Chemin de schéma : "/oneOf"
>
> Message : "Additional properties not allowed", Chemin de données : "/name", Chemin de schéma : "/oneOf/0/additionalProperties"

I don't understand where does the error come from and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

For API Connect I believe you want to use **x-ibm-name** instead of **name**. I was able to get the following spec validated using your above example:

```
info:
  title: Account Information
  x-ibm-name: account-information
  version: 1.0.10
visibility:
  view:
    type: public
  subscribe:
    type: authenticated
plans:
  premium:
    title: Premium
    apis: {}
    rate-limit:
      value: 1000/1minute
      hard-limit: true
    approval: true
  default:
    title: Default Plan
    description: Default Plan
    approval: false
    rate-limit:
      value: 100/hour
      hard-limit: true
apis:
  account:
    $ref: account.yaml
  subscription:
    $ref: subscription.yaml
```

Note: I also removed the **product** field.

You could also use the Design tab to have API Connect create the source automatically in the correct format:

[image]